# How can I display an error message in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I was doing a model for a slider-crank mechanism and I wanted to display an error for when the crank's length exceeds that of the slider arm. With the crank's length as `r2` and the slider's as `r3`, my code went like this:

```
if r3=<r2
    error('The crank's length cannot exceed that of the slider')
end
```

I get the error:

```
???     error('The crank's length cannot exceed that of the slider')
                         |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it please?

Answer (score 12):

When you want to use the `'` character in a string, you have to precede it with another `'` (note the example in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html)):

```
if (r3 <= r2)
  error('The crank''s length cannot exceed that of the slider');
end
```

Also, note the change I made from `=<` to `<=`.

Comment: How about including the actual runtime values, too? Very useful for debugging, especially once your program gets bigger. error('The crank''s length (%f) cannot exceed that of the slider (%f)', r2, r3)

Answer (score 3):

You can print to the error handle as well:

```
fprintf(2,'The crank''s length cannot exceed that of the slider');
```

Comment: Wrong language.  The MATLAB function print is for printing a figure window containing graphics to a printer, and \ doesn't escape '.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the comparison operator should be `<=` not the other way around, unless that was only a typo in your question

Also you should escape the `'` character using `''`